# javascript script tags and ajax issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use ajax on my site for navigation but I'm having a problem with script tags in my pages. (My app is a Rails app but I don't think that makes a difference)

For example, I have a button on my page:

```
<button id="alert">click here</button>
```

and at the bottom:

```
<script>
    $("#alert").click(function() {
        alert("hi there")}
    );
</script>
```

The first time I go to the page, the button works fine. Then, I click around a few links on my Ajax site, go back to the page called with Ajax, and it doesn't work anymore. I heard before 'Ajax strips out the tags' or something, but haven't come up with a solution.

Would `eval()` work? Heard it might do it. How would I implement? I've been working at this for days now and it seems strange there's no simple work around.

Comment: Can you please explain why you simply can't use event delegation.

Comment: does that script tag and its content get generated again each time that ajax page is called?

Comment: When you click around your ajax site do you rewrite the html? replace content? switching to .on would bind the listener to the window so even if the #alert element was added back in it would register.

Comment: @Jonathan Chow - I have several pages with script tags, with different info in each one. So yes, I suppose the tag and content get generated again each time.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris have you tried wrapping $(document).ready around?

Answer (score 4):

**Delegate your events**

```
$(document).on('click', "#alert",function()
      {alert("hi there")}
 });
```

ideally it is better if you do not bind the events to the Document. Try binding the event to the closest possible static element.

Comment: Not sure how this is a solution. Because for your code to work it has to be between script tags, so I still have the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean putting the code in a separate .js file? This wouldn't work for me because I also have dynamic variables, and they don't get reloaded with ajax from a .js file.